# AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath' in robotframework

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, robotframework

It shows me error of AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath' in robot framework and I am using pycharm for it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

All the methods like `find_element_by_name`, `find_element_by_xpath`, `find_element_by_id` etc. are deprecated now.
You should use `find_element(By.` instead.
So, instead of

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("your_xpath")
```

it should be now

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "your_xpath")
```